# Saving and loading ML model

Tags: python, machine-learning, pickle, production-environment, dev-to-production

I have a machine learning model that I save as pickle after I fit it:

```
saved_model = open (path+"clustering_model.pkl", "wb")
pickle.dump(cluster, saved_model)
saved_model.close()
```

I am able to load it back and test it from a different python file by importing the predict method:

I created a test input:

```
processed_responses = {"C1": ["low"], "C2": ["high"],
"C3": ["low"], "C4": ["low"], "C5": ["low"], "C6": ["low"]}

test_data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data = processed_responses)
```

Then I loaded back the model and called the predict method with my test data:

```
saved_model = open(path+"clustering_model.pkl", 'rb')
fitted_model = pickle.load(saved_model)
labels,cost = _predict_cluster(fitted_model, test_data_frame)
```

Everything works on my machine.

The problem started when I tried to load this model from the main application so that I can push everything to dev. For the same test data I get the error message:

```
not enough values to unpack (expected 2 got 1)
```

The error is raised from this method:

```
labels,cost = _predict_cluster(fitted_model, test_data_frame)
```

Insdie the predict I printed what input it receives and it shows me that both model and the test data are received properly:

```
    C1     C2    C3    C4   C5   C6
0   low   high   low  low   low  low
```

This is the fitted model that I loaded back and sent to predict:

```
KModes(cat_dissim=<function matching_dissim at 0x7f60c9c0cb70>, 
init='Random', max_iter=200, n_clusters=8, n_init=15, verbose=0)
```

So far I have not been able to figure out why I get this error. How is it possible that I am able to load the model back on my machine and call the predict with test data but on as part part of the main application on dev?

Thank you.

Comment: In my past projects, I have faced various issues like this due to different versions of libraries in different machines (mostly). So, can you double check if the libraries you are using are the same? Also, how are you running this in main app? I am guessing a python script similar to the script you wrote for test data.

Comment: That is almost exactly what it was :) I have the same versions of libraries but I made some changes to the source code of one of the libraries on my machine and on dev, we have the original version. I run the app to test it, just a small section that triggers this call. Thank you.

Comment: So, the issue is resolved right?

Comment: Yes :) but I don't know how to accept your answer

Comment: don't worry about it. I just wanted to know if it resolved